# Win10 Home & a Dual Quad-Core Mac

Tags: mac, cpu

I have a 2009 Mac Pro with two Quad-Core Processors, and 16 Gigs of RAM, but Windows 10 Home only sees a single processor.  It tells everyone that it's a 2010 Mac Pro, thanks to a hack I found, and a friend willing to do the work. ;) [For the record, I paid $30 for it, off FaceBook Marketplace in July 2019]

I know the simple answer is to get Winders 10 Pro, but I'm retired on a disability, so unless somebody wants to buy it for me... ;)

People write drivers for things like this, and I was hoping somebody knew of one that works...

Answer (score 0):

"Home" editions of Windows have always been limited to a single physical processor, and Windows 10 Home is no exception.  You will need to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise to use both physical processors.

This is an intentional limitation put in place by Microsoft, not a software problem -- there's no way to "fix" it without upgrading.